# Should I decline other opportunity when almost sure to get the job to be honest?

Tags: canada

While seeking a new job, two companies are ready to give me a good offer.

**Employer1**

- a coworker referred me;
- match more the position that I seek;
- VP called me, agreed to the terms, got a confirmation emails related to the discussed terms;
- passed the 15 minutes Canadian background check successfully.

**Current situation with Employer1**

We are waiting for the referrals from previous bosses, HR sent them a 30-45 minutes forms to complete, already talk with my previous bosses, everything will be fine, they already vouched me in the past.

HR are busy, doing honestly their best, will send the contract to sign after 24-48 hours receiving referrals, so probably at the end of the week.

**Employer2**

- pretty cool company, team and project;
- I love them also;
- completed 3 interviews: recruiter, VP, team lead.

**Current situation with Employer2**

VP will call me at the end of the day to discuss about my interest and the terms.

**Challenge**

I am now sure how to handle the call from employer2 VP. There are very friendly people and I feel that I am lying when I say or respond to his question related to interest with:

> I am very eager to join the team

while I almost finished the hiring process of Employer1.

I prefer Employer1 because I got a lot of internal feedback from my ex-coworker and I love how their conduct their business.

Should I take the bet everything will be fine with employer1 and cancel the meeting with employer2 VP? I feel it is not in by best interests to do that.

Thanks

Comment: @gnat yes, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> Should I take the bet everything will be fine with employer1 and cancel the meeting with employer2 VP?

No. You don't have either job until you have signed an offer. It may feel "sneaky" to you, but you can bet both companies have a short list of candidates and they're trying to evaluate a best-fit and commit only when necessary, you should do the same. There are several questions here asking the same thing, and the answer is always "a verbal offer is worth the paper it's printed on."

Sign an offer, then let the other company down gently.

Answer (score 3):

Never stop till you have a signed offer.  But beyond that, you have leverage you don't usually have in this case.

You're not clear whether you strongly prefer job 1 regardless of compensation offered.  If you intend to take job 1 regardless of what happens with job 2, then meet with job 2, string them along, and wait for 1 to clear to keep your options open.  But if you could be tempted over to job 2, then you can just say "I'm interested, but I do have an offer for another position firming up this week," and see how interested they are in landing you - they might fast track and offer more money (or whatever other thing you are most interested in that they can affect).

As a hiring manager, if I'm getting close to hiring someone and hear that, I'd go back and tell my CEO "let's sweeten the offer above whatever we were going to offer and get it to him this week," and then I'd work extra hard on selling you on my position. (I don't even need specifics about the other offer or whatever, I'd just be more aggressive about making the best offer we could.)